# Is it possible to get a string representation of a type name to use as a template literal type?

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I'm trying to return a more concise **compile** error message from a type function and was wondering if it's possible to get a string representation of a type name?

So using [this solution](https://engineering.tableau.com/really-advanced-typescript-types-c590eee59a12) (unfortunately the article does not use anchor links so you'll need to search for ErrorBrand) to create an error message, is it possible to do the following:

```
type ErrorBrand<Err extends string> = Readonly<{
  [k in Err]: void;
}>;

type MyErrorMsgType<T extends string> = ErrorBrand<`The following type caused an error - ${T}`>
```

```
type MyType = {field:string};

type GetStringNameOfType<T> = // converts Type to string name of type

type MyTypeName = GetStringNameOfType<MyType> // outputs 'MyType'

type MyTypeError = MyErrorMsgType<MyTypeName>
// output - The following type caused an error - MyType
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.3.5#code/C4TwDgpgBAogTnA9nAQnAhgOwCYB55xQQAewEOAzlBcHAJaYDmAfFALxQBKE62imAGxC4A3gFgAUFCgBtANZQGsBAF0AXFABuiOtgDckgL7MDEyaEhQAsiALIAKuAi57RUuWxUa9Jqw53UDBxcAAN7AAtoADNEAQFEAHcGRigLaABjdABXCghsKCwiBGQoAFooABIRe0MQ5klzJ2sQR0sOESi6CAFsNW9kw1NGywCrChSOGwDW5xsZ%20okAekWoRCzgMHWyqAjo2PikplSmzJy8gswipEJyuacgA)

Comment: It seems like you want *invalid types* as requested in [microsoft/TypeScript#23689](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/23689).  Since those don't exist, there are only workarounds.  Sometimes I do [this sort of thing](https://tsplay.dev/NaYABN), which uses tuples instead of pure strings.  Tuples are as close to lightweight as you can get here.  And I doubt TypeScript will ever support type-to-string-literal conversion because it would lead to similar confusion and inconsistency as union-to-tuple.  Really you don't want a subtype of string, you want an error message.

Comment: I can write the above up into an answer and expand on it if you want (e.g., explain why type-to-string-literal would be declined if suggested).  Let me know.

Comment: @jcalz that would be great, thank you!

Comment: Actually I am now second guessing myself on whether the type-to-string-literal type would be declined or not.  But I'll write up an answer regardless and point to relevant github issues.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

There is currently no feature in TypeScript that converts a type name into a string  [literal type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#literal-types).  I can't find an existing request for this exact feature (there are somewhat similar things like the declined [microsoft/TypeScript#29944](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/29944) asking for emitting the type name as a string literal *value* at runtime, which is definitely against the rules) so possibly you could [file your own](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/new?template=Feature_request.md).

I wouldn't be *very* optimistic about it being accepted, because type names are essentially an implementation detail and while they are useful for documentation and compiler messages, they're not the sort of thing that you really want observable in the *type system* itself.  (Consider [this comment](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/13298#issuecomment-468375328) on a request to convert [union types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#union-types) into [tuple types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#tuple-types), or [the PR for implementing labeled tuple elements](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/38234) which makes sure to say that these labels don't affect the type system and are just for documentation/display).

Let's imagine that there were a `TypeToString<T>` utility type that would produce the following results:

```
interface A { x: string }
interface B { x: string }
type NameOfA = `It is ${TypeToString<A>}`;
// type NameOfA = "It is A"
type NameOfB = `It is ${TypeToString<B>}`;
// type NameOfB = "It is B"
```

Now people could do funny things like this:

```
function whoAmI<T>(x: T, name: TypeToString<T>): void { }
const a: A = { x: "" };
whoAmI(a, "A"); // okay
```

or

```
interface Wha extends Record<TypeToString<B>, string> { }
const wha: Wha = { B: "hmm" }; // okay?
```

In both cases the output of `TypeToString<T>` is leaking into the type system in places that would normally be reserved for actual literal string values.  And because `A` and `B` are [structurally](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/typescript-in-5-minutes.html#structural-type-system) identical, the compiler considers them the same type:

```
const b: B = a; // okay
```

The *name* of a type doesn't matter to the type system.  It would be very weird for `TypeToString<T>` to be able to extract different information from identical types, and allowing it to do so has some unfortunate implications for assignability in a structural type system.

---

But I don't think you really want these names as string literal *types* that you would use as key names in an interface or as discriminant values of a [discriminated union](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#discriminated-unions), or as types in [declaration files](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-files/introduction.html), right?  Those above examples with `whoAmI` and `Wha` are *misuses* of the feature.

You just want to be able to display type names in *messages* and do other string manipulation or interpolation to format these messages.  It seems to me that the feature you truly want is "invalid types" as requested in [microsoft/TypeScript#23689](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/23689) or possibly "`throw` types" as experimentally implemented in [microsoft/TypeScript#40468](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/40468) (key word is "experimentally"; this particular PR is labeled "Draft" and there's no reason to think it'll be incorporated into a TypeScript release, at least in this form).

The idea is that there'd be a type function like `Invalid<T>` that would throw a compiler error if the type were ever instantiated, and where the error message would be derived from `T` in some way.  For example:

```
function noFunctions<T>(
  t: T extends Function ? 
    Invalid<["Hey,", T, "is a function type. I SAID NO FUNCTIONS!!"]> : 
    T
): void { }

noFunctions(123); // okay
noFunctions(String); // error!
// -------> ~~~~~~
// Hey, 'StringConstructor' is a function type. I SAID NO FUNCTIONS!!
```

You don't need to turn `StringConstructor` into a string literal type `"StringConstructor"`; you just want that string to appear in the error message.

Interestingly enough, the PR at [microsoft/TypeScript#40468](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/40468) actually implemented a `TypeToString<T>` utility type that has the exact behavior you're looking for!  Since this PR has not been merged, and might not ever be merged, it doesn't look like the implications of having an observable `TypeToString<T>` string literal type have been thoroughly discussed or even really considered there.  The existence of the PR makes me a little less confident that `TypeToString<T>` would be declined, but who knows.

In any case you might want to give [ms/TS#23689](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/23689) a .

---

But for now, there is currently no such feature in the language.  All we have are workarounds.  The one I tend to use is a tuple type like I passed to `Invalid<>` above, and just have a property of that type unlikely to be assignable to any real value:

```
type Invalid<T> = { __errMsg: T };

noFunctions(String); // error!
// -------> ~~~~~~
// Argument of type 'StringConstructor' is not assignable to parameter of 
// type 'Invalid<["Hey,", StringConstructor, "is a function. I SAID NO FUNCTIONS!!"]>'.
```

That's not a *great* error message, but

```
["Hey,", StringConstructor, "is a function. I SAID NO FUNCTIONS!!"]
```

appears in there and is at least somewhat human readable if you squint enough.  Tuple types are probably the lightest weight syntax I can think of which places things in a desired order.

Notice how this avoids the `TypeToString<T>` problem, since `["It is", A]` and `["It is", B]` are the same type if `A` and `B` are identical.  I still don't intend these message types to appear anywhere else in the type system or at runtime, but at least assignability doesn't break.

---

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAkgdgNwIYBsCWATAPAFQHxQC8UA3lAPrkQBO1AsgM4DmAXFDlAL4DcAsAFACAZgFc4AY2BoA9nChxpAMTGSZcBrjwAKAVCjA2HCAA9gEOBgZRlEqbKgB+WIlSYsAbQBEACQggANJ7+7MGeaFZIUKK2agB0sFAAygCCMAAiUAByAPLWAKqZAMI4MNmZiQCEFZ4AugSGAgCUbAjSmKRcAgIKNqqyDFoAjABMAMyN3FAA9FNQ0gDWSCDdSip26lqJwNRocEwT07M01NLUFQIzUAC0N7dXBAB+T88Xs74BUADkWzt7hf3bESSU6fKDhKCRaJ9ODxGBJVIZHL5IolMqVc78S7JahMEQAW3MwDmQn04Gg322uyY-3UgOB1FB4IURKQDAYaCYcCQACMUNBgNIoGAkNQkASzNRiVBXqTIF94Mh0NgvO9AsEflSaQw6QLqKFwZC1nEEil0llcooCsVSuUqrU8J9Yl1BC6BKA5TgyThpBq9poiOwoCYzBYrNrfkwoAAfeT47k0aNQbkc3ZEmPc6TSPlIOQxuAiFAoRNiDAQIS7CAYRxQAAGABISDhODWoCxdIHg+ZLFA0kgzNXPL2zJ5Wx3TF2rMkB8kR4Yg+PQ1AAEIDpez+QQBA0Pgu1M0IRIcTQKdkYxscNUzr8PfUA9H5cdM9QC97K-u6CZMUQbJCKfEGswES4INp6kDer6TBYMkeDNjulzvlkX4-n+UCeIBYKTp4bpkohBI-iu-7ocBjZej6lJ+kuME1nBswIZ+eFCARqFEVYa7OlC6xQAA7gAFtIyR4jAmhaE+ODBFyBKGKREGaM0UCtO0ZCcAI4gAhCbAoaebCeCOPACLx-GCVoSChDOByXAsSzOqptJJmwTFaahuk7gZAkwFo3KhGu5mzJZHwmEeYBEihK4MIKwA8eCDB8VxVgiGAEJWJ4M7YXKhQBskLl8W5xmhIUng+XMiwgA4+nZUZdB9jxsSihY0h4lojRQFgUAAAyxAArNWkRsJ5qFTjG3mTJc2poIWz4xXFCWsv1QTOjed7QAA6jxkSdouABKECqdQ2CgRA4HkZBlHBC+TAEEpKlqbxSBsCtkTEGQS7aTxeJ4s5hzPlI43JVhrr8EAA)

Comment: brilliant explanation as always, thanks for taking the time to thoroughly explain this! And yes, you're right, my use case is only for the type name to appear within an error message, not to use it for anything else

Comment: As for the Invalid type, `type-plus` provides a great utility called the `Failed` type which looks like this: `declare const uniSym: unique symbol; interface Failed<Msg extends string> { [uniSym]: Msg }`. Which, in turn, shows a message like this: `Failed<"This is a message">`.