# Typescript property name based on Generic Parameter Type

Tags: typescript, generics, mapped-types

Is there a way to create a `Generic` type in Typescript that contains a property based on the parameter type?

What I am looking for is something similar to mapped types. But instead of using the property names, I'd like to use the type name.

Example use case.
I see a lot of APIs return the following structure

```
{
  "total": 100,
  "skip": 0,
  "limit": 30,
  "a property named based on the type being queried": [
    // the actual data requested
  ]
}
```

What I would like to do is create a generic that would be able to receive that data.
I'm thinking something like

```
interface ListEnvelope<T> {
    [T as `${T}s`]: T[] // This is not valid Typescript. Its sudocode for what I'd like to do
    total: number
    skip: number
    limit: number
}
interface Product {
    id: number
    title: string
}
const ListEnvelope<Product> = {
  total: 100,
  skip: 0,
  limit: 30,
  Products: [
    // All of my products
  ]
}
```

That way I could program generically against all of the endpoints of the API.

Comment: Type names in TypeScript are not observable by the type system; you will need to pass in a string literal type yourself if you want that, perhaps like [this](https://tsplay.dev/mL2Eew).  Or you could write up a mapping from strings to types and then look up the name in the mapping like [this](https://tsplay.dev/w17bOm).  Does that fully address your question? If so I could write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing? (Pls mention @jcalz to notify me if you reply)

Comment: @jcalz Thank you for your answer. If the type name is really not observable. Then I guess your recommendations are the best we're going to get.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In TypeScript, type *names* are completely unobservable by the type system.  (See [Is it possible to get a string representation of a type name to use as a template literal type?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/70259150/2887218) and its answers for more information.)  So there's no way in which you can automatically get the string [literal type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#literal-types) `"Product"` from the interface named `Product`.  If you want behavior like this, you'll have to set it up yourself.

For example, you could add a second type argument to `ListEnvelope` which takes the desired key name:

```
type ListEnvelope<K extends string, T> = { [P in K]: T[] } & {
  total: number
  skip: number
  limit: number
}
```

which you would use like this:

```
type LEP = ListEnvelope<"Products", Product>;
/* type LEP = { Products: Product[]; } & 
   {  total: number; skip: number; limit: number; } */

const x: ListEnvelope<"Products", Product> = {
  total: 100,
  skip: 0,
  limit: 30,
  Products: [
    // All of my products
  ]
}
```

Or you could create a mapping from names to types in advance, like this:

```
interface TypeMap {
  Product: Product,
  OtherType: OtherType
  // ... all others
}
```

And then `ListEnvelope` would look up the name in that mapping:

```
type ListEnvelope<T extends TypeMap[keyof TypeMap]> =
  { [K in keyof TypeMap as T extends TypeMap[K] ? `${K}s` : never]: TypeMap[K][] } & {
    total: number
    skip: number
    limit: number
  }
```

which you would use like this:

```
type LEP = ListEnvelope<Product>;
/* type LEP = { Products: Product[]; } & 
   {  total: number; skip: number; limit: number; } */

const x: ListEnvelope<Product> = {
  total: 100,
  skip: 0,
  limit: 30,
  Products: [
    // All of my products
  ]
}
```

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?noErrorTruncation=true#code/HYQwtgpgzgDiDGEAEApeIA2AvJBvAUPkkqJLAsgKIAeMGAlvPQC4YCeACiFFANIRsAcuGQFixZmxjIAMvSjNKwAG4QMAe2kAeXkgjVmEYABMoSBQCd6wAOYAaJABUAfEgC8eJAG0OSa0l4AXQAuJy9ApABfJAAyPCJxCXVmTFDgAFcwACMICwTEqABrehg0zJy8xOIGMBYy7Nz8qKbrQwsAMwokDgt1Y3T4Zniqv2N6iqaJFgwIUMtrGybIwkTJaSQZSl8POQUlVQ1tACIevoHmKCOHU-7B5wBuJoB6ACokNdkt908b86hQ36DcL3KKxJCTYi4JIpDDjXIgoolOEWEE1Ookcrw0EvJ4rcTwdTABRIaihXaKFRqTQQLQnXq3C5Xbr086uDxiKrMZKpJAARgADPy7BDEaUkEKIWjmKEAMwSkaAi6hLwQ4hPJ5IACCGAwSHU7SQYDYSBgLMGUAhgSWCWWCVI0DgiCQAFUoBByQB5dqOKQQYRkYbiVq5TpOxWBxL0MYYhqVTnTWbmZhWWzWyPANqh5Ae5gAC1yPvWHMS7XU6jmyYWjxGWRAFmR1fEtvTma6hYgAFkQDAI+JFQCzcxhSMc-mLO3QqOC77rU0Pht5BSDtStI49AYjKYnL6uzAvIUBPrt9Jd4E2RCoV5dP4D2wj+3d0huE514YTGYH92rxEAPxIAAGAAkuC8JEUD-kgaQQKoFghMenZfkE4SgnExactysIxhMIzEKKyKqkgUr4SMzbiPOmzbAueyUocNKKg8zxvORXzssyZzmgO7HMMCKHgjhULvBhDbmMUYoZLGqL0LU0pYVi0Q4nixAEkSQyklRS5Uto9HfGh0I8gK8pVHh4rDlURFIHKpmJIq-zeAR6pajqeoGkaJqDhaIxWokpG2pEQA)

Comment: Why didn't you use your examples from your comments? https://tsplay.dev/mL2Eew
Much easier to understand

Comment: I'm not sure what example you're talking about, if it's assigning to the `x` variable then I just added it.  If not, what am I missing?